# In temp.deduct.partial, why is a parameter pack less specialized?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

In [temp.deduct.partial#8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.partial#8), there's an example:

```cpp
template<class... Args>           void f(Args... args);         // #1
template<class T1, class... Args> void f(T1 a1, Args... args);  // #2
template<class T1, class T2>      void f(T1 a1, T2 a2);         // #3

f();                // calls #1
f(1, 2, 3);         // calls #2
f(1, 2);            // calls #3; non-variadic template #3 is more specialized
                    // than the variadic templates #1 and #2
```

Call #1 is trivial, since there's only one viable specialization.

For call #2, `f₁` and `f₂` are viable. We synthesize `f₁(X)` and `f₂(X, Y)`. We then do type deduction both ways.

First `f₂(X, Y)` against `f₁(Args... args)`, which deduces `Args` to be `X, Y`.

Then `f₁(X)` against void `f₂(T1 a1, Args... args)`, which deduces `T1` as `X`, and `Args` as empty.

So deduction succeeds in both ways, and neither is more specialized than the other.

Could we be saved by [temp.deduct.partial#11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.partial#11)?

> If, after considering the above, function template F is at least as specialized as function template G and vice-versa, and if G has a trailing parameter pack for which F does not have a corresponding parameter, and if F does not have a trailing parameter pack, then F is more specialized than G.

Doesn't look like this helps. Let `F=f₁, G=f₂`, then `G` does indeed have a trailing parameter pack for which `F` does not have a corresponding parameter. But `F` has a trailing parameter pack, so this does not apply.

Did I misread anything in the standard, or is the answer maybe found somewhere else entirely?

Comment: I can't follow your `f1(X)` and `f2(X, Y)` elaborations. There is no `f` being called with one argument at any point here? When you say "for call #2", you mean `f(1, 2, 3);`, right? So where does `f1(X)` come from? And how would you ever deduce `Args` as empty for function template #2 with any of the given calls? I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: This is how partial ordering of function templates is done. For each function template, produce a transformed template where each template parameter is replaced by a synthesized unique type. Then do type deduction from each transformed template to the other, original template. If deduction succeeds one way only, one is more specialized than the other.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of that.

Comment: @knatten:  Adding this as a comment as I'm unsure if it would constitute an answer. There have been a couple of issues with partial ordering. [1. 1157. Partial ordering of function templates is still underspecified](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1157) and [2.Issues with partial ordering](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2160)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting links, @P.W! I don't think those issues are relevant in this case though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was [answered](https://twitter.com/knatten/status/1102527724139225088) by Simon Brand on Twitter. The key is in [temp.deduct#type-10.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#type-10.2):

> During partial ordering, if Ai was originally a function parameter pack:
>   (...) if Pi is not a function parameter pack, template argument deduction fails.

In this case, when doing `f₁(X)` against `f₂(T1 a1, Args... args)`, `X` was originally a function parameter pack. `T1` is however not a function parameter pack, so deduction fails.

Since we can deduce `f₁` from `f₂`, but not the other way around, `f₂` is more specialized.